# Change <pre> block contents upon textarea update

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get contents between the `<pre>...</pre>` tag to be rendered by JavaScript, where the contents is dynamic. What I hope to do is to type an input within a textarea to update display in the `<pre>` tags.

I'm unsure how to specify the contents within the `<pre>` tags to take the value from textarea on every textarea update.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so what exactly have you tried? This site is more for specific problems you come across, rather than a site where we write tutorials for you.

Comment: Hi maybe I was too hasty in posting my question, I was trying to get an alternative answer from using innerHTML. I got my question answered. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeing the code you're working with would help greatly, but if I'm reading correctly, this should help. Assuming HTML like this:

```
<textarea id="type"></textarea>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

This option uses pure javascript:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('type'),
    pre = document.getElementById('output');

if(textarea.addEventListener) {
    textarea.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
        pre.textContent = this.value;
    });
} else {
    textarea.attachEvent('onkeyup',function(){
        pre.textContent = this.value;
    });
}
```

This code block uses the jQuery library for brevity:

```
$('#type').on('keyup',function(){
    $('#output').text($(this).val());
});
```

Note that in both situations, I am setting the *text* of the `<pre>`, not the HTML. This allows you to enter HTML characters like `<` into the textarea and have them be properly escaped in your `<pre>` element.

[**Pure JavaScript Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/UmM5Q/)

[**jQuery Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/nepwd/)

If you don't wish to change the `<pre>` until after you leave the `<textarea>`, then just change `'keyup'` and `'onkeyup'` to `'change'` and `'onchange'` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the [`onchange`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event to the `input`, and then simply copy its value to `pre`:

```
<pre id="pre">Type something</pre>
<textarea id="text" rows="20" cols="20" />
​
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("text").onchange = function () {
  document.getElementById("pre").innerHTML = this.value;  
};
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mMQEe/1/)**.​

Comment: it's also not a self-closing element, hence why `</body></html>` appears within the textarea in your demo.